# labeling in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and still learning, I have created a database and some models but I got stuck with meaningful labels in Django Admin. This is the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    min_order = models.IntegerField()
    max_order = models.IntegerField()
    units = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.ForeignKey(Quantity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    objects = ProductManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
```

And I get this:
[image]

I want Product object (3) to be replaced byt the product_name. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`__str__`** method [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and return the `product_name` instead:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy... been reading all Meta class definitions :) Thanks @Willem Van Onsem